# Connecting between the network to the gps provider

Tags: java, android, geolocation

I created an application that generates every 10 minutes a location if I moved 200 meter from the last location.
It's based on the network and the gps provider.

My problem is if I'm on the same place for a lot of time something wrong happend.
Let's assume that the gps provider generates a location with 600 accuracy and the network provider generates a location with 800 accuracy.
My app will choose the gps provider and the next time that the gps will generate a location would be when I pass the 200 radios but looks like that the network location keep generating locations and some of them might be more accurate and then my location is changed while I'm on the same place.

This is a problem since staying in the same place for hours generates for me tone of locations instead of 1(which is what I'm looking for).

I didn't attached code because it's more theoretical question I guess.

**EDIT** code attachment

The update request:

```
mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, TEN_SECONDS*6*10, TEN_METERS*20, listener);
```

Choosing between the locations:

```
    if(gpsLocation == null || gpsLocation.getAccuracy() > 1000)
    {
        if(!(networkLocation == null || networkLocation.getAccuracy() > 1000))
            location = networkLocation;
    }
    else
        if(networkLocation == null)
        {
            if(gpsLocation.getAccuracy() < 1000)
                location = gpsLocation;
        }
        else
            if(gpsLocation.getAccuracy() < networkLocation.getAccuracy() && gpsLocation.getAccuracy() < 500)
                location = gpsLocation;
            else
                if(networkLocation.getAccuracy() < 1000)
                    location = networkLocation;
    if(location!=null)
    {
        Message.obtain(mHandler,
                UPDATE_LATLNG,
                location.getLatitude() + ", " + location.getLongitude()).sendToTarget();
         if (mGeocoderAvailable) 
            doReverseGeocoding(location);
    }
```

Here is the handler:

```
   mHandler = new Handler() 
    {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
        {
            if(msg.what == UPDATE_ADDRESS)
            {
                LocationService.this.address = (String) msg.obj;
                new SendLocation(LocationService.this.id,(String)msg.obj); //sends location to the db
                LocationService.this.gpsLocation = null;
                LocationService.this.networkLocation = null;
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get the location by GPS provider, it would be more accurate, so if next time you get a location by Network provider and it differs by more than say 500 meters then store this as the value, if the location is less than this value is given by network provider skip it. If the location is provided by the GPS store this as the current location.